# unable to switch screen in Kubuntu 14.10

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, monitor

I recently moved to Ubuntu from Windows and I'm using Kubuntu 14.10 now. 
I have a laptop with an external monitor. The problem is, I am not able to switch between the monitors with Kubuntu running. The only way to use the other monitor is to turn off the computer, plug/unplug the external monitor, and then turn it on again.
I do not have an NVIDIA card (I've seen some threads about NVIDIA causing the trouble).

Before you ask, here is the output of lspci and xrandr.

> satellite-R630:~$ lspci | grep VGA
>
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
>
> Satellite-R630:~$ xrandr -q
>
> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
>
> Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 1024, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
>   default connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
>      1280x1024      77.0*

I don't know why doesn't xrandr show two screens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to System Settings > Shortcuts and gestures > Global Keyboard Shortcuts. Select KDE component: KDE Daemon.

Edit shortcut for Switch Display.

[image]

On my laptop the Display button is seen as Meta-P.

Hitting that key would switch between internal, external, mirror and extended display.